# Python git log -S "text" filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

I want to run this specific git command:

```
 git log -S "text" filepath
```

In python (3.5).

I've tried this:

```
import git
g = git.Git(repopath) 
print(g.log("-S \"text\"", filepath))
```

Both using the absolute path of the file I want to log (filepath) and the relative path of the file from the repo root (repopath).
In both cases, the output is empty, whereas I do get the log without the "-S \"text\"" part.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the syntax is:

```
import git
g = git.Git(repopath) 
print(g.log("-S ","text", filepath))
```